# Angular Javascript inside php foreach inside HTML

Tags: php, html, angularjs, foreach

I am trying to make a simple shopping website using mainly `PHP` and `HTML`. 
Inside `PHP`, I created objects from a `class`, and those objects are in `array`.
Now inside `HTML`, I am printing each `object's photo and name` using `PHP's` `foreach`. 
Since this is a shopping website, I have added a `FORM` under each item photo where the customer can type in the number of the items they wish to purchase. The default value is 0. 
Now, using a`ngularJS`, What I want to do is:
1)when the value(the number of the items they want) is 0, nothing happens and the webpage prints nothing.
2)when the value is more than 0, print the number * the price right next to the `form`, so the user can see in real time how much the total is going to be for that specific item.

Here is my code..

```
<?php
class Stock{
    public $name; //in real program it is private. 
    public $price;
}

//Create objects and initialize them by giving each of them name and price
//Assume there are 3 objects
$items = array($object1, $object2, $object3);
?>

//now in HTML code
<form method="POST" action="order.php">
    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
        <!--Print name and price of each -->
    <input type="text" value="0" name="<?php echo $item->name; ?>"> {{ <!--*****--> }}
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I want to print the product of the number * price of the item right next to the form only if the value is greater than 0. I tried adding `ng-model="quantity"` inside input tag and wrote `{{ quantity * $_POST[$item->name] }}`. However, this does not fully work. This does print the product, but because it is inside `foreach`, when I change the value in the `form` for an item, the values for the other items' form change along with it.  How can you apply `angularJS` only for the specific item?

Comment: Line 2: I meant

Comment: I meant to say " Now inside html, I am printing each object's NAME and PRICE using php's foreach. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop must be in angular to do this.

So you could bind it as a model ..

**FORM.PHP**

```
<div ng-app="appModule">
<form action="order.php" method="post" ng-controller="orderFormController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
        {{ item.name }} (price - {{ item.price }}): <input type="text" value="0" name="{{item.name}}" ng-model="qty[item.name]" />
        Total: <span ng-if="qty[item.name] > 0">{{ item.price*qty[item.name] }}</span>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**MODULE.JS**

```
var app = angular.module("appModule", []); 
app.controller("orderFormController", function($scope) {
    // $scope.itemList - ajax your item list here
    $scope.itemList = [
        {name: 'Pencil', 'price': 10},
        {name: 'Paper', 'price': 2},
        {name: 'Folder', 'price': 13},
    ];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the value inside the input tag. Refer to HTML input value Attribute on W3 Schools.

```
<input value='<?php // your php code ?>' />
```

[input value w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_value.asp)

[input value w3c schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_value)

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Don't confuse the W3C (who create web standards)  with W3Schools (purveyors of low quality tutorials).

Comment: My bad. Updating the answer. You could have just commented and avoid downvoting tho, but whatever.

Comment: This just pre-populates the input. How does this deal with the problem (of displaying the price next to the field) that the question is asking about?

Comment: Given that angularjs has the two-way-binding you can work with just the prepopulate instead of updating an outside value :)